# Can I find out when a cell is queued?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a couple of things in my custom `UITableViewCell`'s that I'd like to clean up before the cell gets queued. In a normal view, I'd put these kinds of calls in `-(void)dealloc`, but as they're being re-used rather than having an instance each, they won't dealloc. For now, I'd just like to print out a text in the log, `NSLog(@"Cell out");` when the cell is queued, or "done".

I'm really just looking for something like `-(void)didQueue` in the cell-class, but my searches haven't shown anything.

I just found `-(void)prepareForReuse`, but I need more like `prepareForQueue`. I have to know when it's on its way out, not back in.

Random thought..: Searching for when the cell leaves the screen (or a bit after) might do exactly the same as what I'm looking for, but I'm thinking that costs a lot of processing..

Comment: Why? What is the difference from the cell point of view?

Comment: I think `prepareForReuse` is only called when the cell is going to be directly reused, so it's basically the same as the `prepareForQueue` method that you want.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 6+ the table view delegate will receive `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` which tells you when the cell is not being used any more (irrelevant of queueing).

That said, `prepareForReuse` would generally be considered the correct place for the code you describe. If it isn't then you are probably assigning the cell responsibility it shouldn't have.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm actually playing videos in each cell. The cells each have their own `AVPlayer` and playerLayer. Is this bad practice? Should I rather have a collection of AVPlayers in the tableView, or maybe just one? To give you a picture of what I'm trying to do, it's very similar to the app "Vine", if you've used it.

Comment: Ok, no, that makes sense. Having a player for each cell enables your reuse, you do need to know when the cell stops being displayed. I guess the user starts playing (not automated).

Comment: No, I'm doing automated, but so far I tried something like `if(cell is within some frame){stop the cell currently playing, start this one}`, the problem is that if the user scrolls 10 cells down, the playing cell is being re-used, and I can no longer fetch the AVPlayer to stop it, but it still plays. Now when you mention it, I think maybe my way of doing this actually forces a new instance of `AVPlayer` each `cellForRow:`. I'll try to rather keep the player and switch the content. Thanks.